# git octopus merge 'silently' not merging some branches

Tags: git, merge, octopus

I am having some unexpected results that seem to be based on the ordering of branches given to git merge when performing an octopus merge.

The following script will replicate my situation

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm -rf TEMP

# create area to work in
mkdir TEMP
cd TEMP/
git init

# work on master
echo "hello world" > file
git add file 
git commit -m "initial commit"

# create branch which is at the same point as master
git branch hasnt_moved

# create another branch 1 commit ahead
git checkout -b feature_branch_with_work
echo "some interesting work" > other_file
git add other_file 
git commit -m "work on feature branch"

git checkout master

# always should also have some work ahead of master
git checkout -b always
echo "some work on always" > other_other_file
git add other_other_file 
git commit -m "work on always branch"

# back to master
git checkout master

# now try a merge
#git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus always hasnt_moved feature_branch_with_work

# however if I had ran this then it would be merged in
#git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus hasnt_moved always feature_branch_with_work

# I would also expect this to give the same resutls
#git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus always feature_branch_with_work hasnt_moved
```

Here is the state of my git tree after running the above script
[image: branches before any merge]

You can see the 3 commented out lines at the end, below is each line and the graph resulting from running that command on the tree (produced via `gitk --all`, after running each command you can get 'back' to the start via `git reset --hard hasnt_moved`)

The following 2 cases are as expected (pay attention to the ordering of the branch arguments)

`git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus hasnt_moved always feature_branch_with_work`

[image: expected results form merge]

`git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus always feature_branch_with_work hasnt_moved`

[image: expected results form merge]

This final case produces unexpected results, as the always branch is not included in the final merged master branch (pay attention to the ordering of the branch arguments).

`git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus always hasnt_moved feature_branch_with_work`

[image: actual results from merge]

If I run the merges one by one I get the expected result:

```
git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus always
git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus hastn_moved
git merge --no-edit --strategy=octopus feature_branch_with_work
```

[image: manual results given expected results]

I am wondering why the ordering of the commits given to octopus merge can sometimes cause the `always` branch to not be merged into master.

Comment: This smells like a bug in Git.  I'll ping the Git mailing list later today (I have to head in to work).

Comment: @jszakmeister that was my thoughts too, was planning on doing the same after a few days without answers.

Comment: So after digging around in git-merge-octopus it seems that the error case is NOT calling that script, but the successful cases are. Going to try dig a little and then report the bug.

Comment: It looks like a branch name is accidentally being used as a message.  I'm not sure why just yet, but it most certainly smells like a bug now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're stumbling onto a legacy syntax.  It turns out that `git merge` used to have the form:

```
git merge <msg> HEAD <commit>...
```

It's still supported for legacy reasons.  Your merge command:

```
git merge --no-edit always hasnt_moved feature_branch_with_work
```

is accidentally stumbling on it.  In this case `always` is seen as the message, and `hasnt_moved` is at the same revision as HEAD.  As a result, git is treating this command as:

```
git merge --no-edit -m "always" feature_branch_with_work
```

I'm not sure of the former syntax of git, but it seems to me that if it expected to see the actual word `HEAD` that git should be a little more strict before dropping to this syntax.  However, I doubt that was the case.

You can work around it by explicitly providing a message with the `-m` parameter:

```
git merge --no-edit -m "Merge always, hasnt_moved, and feature_branch_with_work"
    \ always hasnt_moved feature_branch_with_work
```

Then the octopus merge happens as expected.

BTW, you can see the old syntax of `git merge` on the [`git-merge` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if it would be better behavior to ensure that the first parameter is not a branch name.  Seems like that would be a good indication that it's not the `git merge <msg> HEAD <commit>...` form.